# Using properties file constants as annotation values

Tags: spring-boot, validation, properties-file

I'm successfully loading messages for validation constraints from my properties file/s (i18n) but as I'm writing client side validation it's becoming clear that one source for both messages and constraint values could make the whole process less cumbersome.

In short: is there any way to load a value such as 20 for the size annotation from the properties file?

```
@Size(max=20)
private String password;
```

I have tried lines like:

```
@Size(max="${constraint.value}")
// or
@Size(max=Integer.valueOf("#{constraint.value}"))
```

But the value needs to be an Integer and a constant.

Edit1:
The client-side validation logic is done all over again in a form of a separate library, just the values like (5,10) for (min,max) are sticking out. (Using thymeleaf)

```
<script type="text/javascript" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:inline="javascript">
    //...
    // reading message from properties file
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var errMessage = /*[[#{Size.user.userName}]]*/ 'default';
    /*]]>*/

    // adding a constraint to validationObj linked with one <input> element
    validationObj.addSizeConstraint(ft.keyup,5,10,errMessage);
    //...
</script>
```

Edit2:
Thanks to @Pavel Horal comment i made it work like this:

On the server side:

```
public static final int USERNAME_MAX_SIZE=20;

@Size(max=USERNAME_MAX_SIZE)
private String userName;
```

On the client side (or to the client side since it's preprocessed on the server side with thymeleaf) I'm getting this value like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:inline="javascript">
    //...
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        var value =/*[[${T(com.project.FormModel).USERNAME_MAX_SIZE}]]*/ 20;
    /*]]>*/
    //...
</script>
```

Which in my view is a better solution since I'm keeping all the values outside of javascript code. Thanks!

Comment: You can use class constants (`public static final` fields) and share those. Or you can read validation parameters via `Validator` (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#getConstraintsForClass-java.lang.Class-). However I would not care about repeating validation logic... back-end validation and front-end validations (mainly with single page applications) might have a slightly different purpose and logic.

Comment: @PavelHoral Added edit to clarify. The public static final fields I'm not sure of because I don't know a way to load them with thymeleaf, will research it though. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne You mean the form model class with bunch of javax validation annotations assigned to fields like: userName and password? Seems like a waste of space.

Answer (score 0):

`@Size` annotation's max parameter only accepts an integer, so the below will ***not*** work anyway.

```
@Size(max="${constraint.value}")
```

On the other hand below also ***not*** working. `"#{constraint.value}"` will not resolve value from your property file. Also `"${constraint.value}"` will not work here too.

```
@Size(max=Integer.valueOf("#{constraint.value}"))
```

And for all annotations, annotation parameters should be constants by definition. So I actually can't imagine a potential solution for your problem.